# Dependency Injection in .NET Core Main() Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have a library with a class that I instantiate in the `Main()` method of my .NET Core Web API (`netcoreapp2.2`) for retrieving the Web API's configuration:

```c#
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var configBuilder = new ConfigBuilder("configuration-v1.json").Build();

    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseConfiguration(configuration)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

The constructor `ConfigBuilder` is:

```c#
public AwsConfigurationBuilder(string configKey, IAmazonS3ClientAdapter s3Client)
```

My `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` is:

```c#
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddScoped<IAmazonS3ClientAdapter, AmazonS3ClientAdapter>()
        .AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

And I am getting the following error concerning `ConfigBuilder` instantiation:

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 's3Client' of 'ConfigBuilder.ConfigBuilder(string, IAmazonS3ClientAdapter)' [Foo.BarService]csharp(CS7036)
```

Is it just not possible to do dependency injection in the service's `Main` method?

Comment: That's not how DI works. If you want DI to create your object, then you can't invoke the constructor directly yourself (in other words, avoid the `new` keyword). I highly suggest you watch [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412) if you're new to DI concepts.

Comment: `new Whatever()` is not DI. That being said, you cannot use DI within `Main` as that is literally the first thing of your application that runs. It’s only later that DI becomes available.

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

The starting point of any Dependency Injection application is called the Composition Root. The composition root is where we define all the mappings of the application. Loosely put mappings between abstraction and concretion.

Once this mapping is defined the object creation is handed over to the DI framework. DI framework then traverses through these mappings and creates objects for us.

A very good analogy that @Mark Seemann gave in his seminal book on DI is that imagine your code as a little kid. That kid is not allowed to open the fridge. Now if the kid wants to eat something he asks his mom about it. DI framework is the mom who knows what's there in the fridge and how to serve it to the kid.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, assuming you injected your service properly, and not sure if this is a good idea or not but...

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = CreateWebHostBuilder(args);
    var host = builder.Build(); 
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

        var aws = services.GetService<AwsConfigurationBuilder>();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you cannot apply it within the `Main` method as that is the entrypoint to your application (and its a static method, not a constructor).

You are also instantiating the class by creating a new object (`new ConfigBuilder`), that's not how you are supposed to use dependency injection.

You are using ASP .NET core. The wiring for your dependencies is done within `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` [after which](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.0) you can use the dependencies. For example, by specifying the needed dependencies (interfaces and/or classes) in your Controller constructor.

You can find a more in-depth explanation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection.